# Clang auto variable template bug

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, variable-templates

I went to see if you could use auto in a variable template declaration.

```
template <typename T>
auto F = T{};
```

Fine, but as soon as you try to use it, clang craps.

```
int f = F<int>; // error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'auto'
auto f = F<int>; // Stacktrace
decltype(F<int>) f = F<int>; // StackFace
std::cout << std::is_same<int, decltype(F<int>)>::value; // false
std::cout << typeid(decltype(F<int>)).name(); // Stacktrace
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(F<int>), decltype(F<int>)>::value; // true
```

Any combination of `decltype(auto)`, `auto` doesn't work even though it says that `auto` is an lvalue.

```
int f = static_cast<int>(F<int>); // error: static_cast from 'auto' to 'int' is not allowed
```

I've never seen auto act this way before. Is it because of variable templates or because of how clang treats auto?

Comment: I think it's probably just not fully implemented yet.

Comment: "// Stacktrace" Whenever you get that, the message "clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script." is included in the output. Please do so, this is pretty clearly a bug in clang, and the clang developers are much more likely to be able to give a useful response than the folks here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be addressed in the latest version of `clang`; putting that into a file and calling

```
clang++ -std=c++1y test.cpp
```

gives me no errors.

```
kevinushey@Kevin-MBP:~$ clang++ -v
clang version 3.5 (trunk 201469)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I got that bug today too with an up to date repository : clang version 3.5 (202594) Target: x86_64-pc-win32 Thread model: posix